# Link in kanban view

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

How add link in kanban view after click on item, i need to open view form for current id.

Now in below example I can't click on item.

```xml
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_report_365_kanban">
    <field name="name">report.my.kanban</field>
    <field name="model">report.my</field>
    <field name="type">kanban</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <kanban>
            <templates>
            <t t-name="kanban-box">
                    <div class="oe_product_vignette">
                        <div class="oe_product_desc">
                            <h3><field name="name" /></h3>
                            <h4>
                                <field name="user_id"/>
                            </h4>
                            <ul>
                                <field name="date"/>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </t>
            </templates>
        </kanban>
    </field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add class:

```
oe_kanban_global_click
```

try to add it here:

```xml
<div class="oe_product_vignette oe_kanban_global_click">
```